# linking against llvm libraries

Tags: llvm

I'm developing a llvm-based compiler and when I try to generate executable file the following error occurs:

./bin/llvmcode.s:35: undefined reference to `operator new[](unsigned long)'

Note that in the generated IR, the function '@_Znam' is called  which is located in one of llvm libraries. So, I should have linked the generated assembly file with that library. Here is the code I used to do that:

```
llvm-as ./bin/llvmcode.ll
llc ./bin/llvmcode.bc
g++ -g ./bin/llvmcode.s \`llvm-config --cppflags --ldflags --libs core jit native\` -O3 -o executable -rdynamic
```

What's wrong with this code? Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301899/llinking-znam-and-znwm ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [llinking @\_Znam and @\_Znwm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301899/llinking-znam-and-znwm)