# llinking @_Znam and @_Znwm

Tags: c++, llvm, std

I'm new to c++ programming and currently working on an `llvm` front-end development project. When I link the object files created by llc, my linker cannot locate the following functions. I know that these are standard c++ library functions but using `-lstdc++` doesn't work. Now my question is that where are these functions defined and how can I link them with my object files, and actually what do they do?

```
declare noalias i8* @_Znam(i64)

declare noalias i8* @_Znwm(i64)
```

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of your older question http://stackoverflow.com/q/12750526 ? What's the difference between this one and the old one?

Comment: Yes, but as no one answered that question I tried to ask it in another way

Answer (score 4):

These functions are standard C++ library functions, in particular, `operator new[](unsigned long)` and `operator new(unsigned long)`. They should be provided by your C++ runtime library. Depending on which compiler you're using this will be libsupc++ or libc++abi or libcxxrt.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it seems that these libraries aren't installed on my system. How should I install them? I'm using g++ to link the object files and my system is ubuntu 11.04

Comment: Then you definitely have libsupc++. Either directly, or as a part of libstdc++.

Comment: So, why cannot g++ locate these functions? I used -lsupc++. Also, I found that libsupc++.a is in folder /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.5, so added this folder to the search path but this error occurred again

Comment: How have you generated your IR?

Comment: In fact, I'm writing a compiler for a DSL in java and in order to learn how to generate intermediate code I utilized the llvm language reference and the demo version of clang. When I was working on arrays I saw that clang generated a call to @_Znam and also a call to @_Znwm when allocating memory for an object, therefore I did what clang did, but encountered the the following errors: 'undefined reference to operator new(unsigned long)' & 'undefined reference to operator new[](unsigned long)'

Comment: These are C++-level constructs. And you should not use them blindly :) In fact, you should not use them at all! Most probably, mangling is a bit different for your platform.

Comment: In my language all arrays are dynamic (i.e. their size is determined at runtime), so for example if I want to define an array of integers  I can't use '%x = alloca [%len x i32]', and if I shouldn't use @_Znam (like clang) then how do I allocate memory for them?

Comment: You can use any way of allocating memory available for you. E.g. via ordinary malloc.