# Why does std::deque allocate memory for its elements in the default constructor?

Tags: c++

With g++ 5.4 compiler and GNU standard library libstdc++.so.6, default constructor of `std::vector` creates an empty container initializing only internal bookkeeping data members on stack. It allocates  buffer on heap for data elements later (when the fist element is inserted). Until recently, I thought it was a common behavior for any standard sequential container with dynamically allocated memory.

However, `std::deque` works differently. Tracing the following code

```
#include <deque> 
int main() {
    std::deque<int> d;
    return 0;
}
```

with `ltrace` gives

```
__libc_start_main(0x4024fa, 1, 0x7ffd088be0f8, 0x405bd0 <unfinished ...>
_ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev(0x608351, 0xffff, 0x7ffd088be108, 160)        = 0
__cxa_atexit(0x401f20, 0x608351, 0x608210, 0x7ffd088bded0)            = 0
_Znwm(64, 8, 0, 8)                                                    = 0x7b4c20
_Znwm(512, 128, 0, 128)                                               = 0x7b4c70
_ZdlPv(0x7b4c70, 0x7b4c70, 128, 0x7b4c70)                             = 1
_ZdlPv(0x7b4c20, 0x7b4c20, 8, 0x7b4c20)                               = 0
_ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev(0x608351, 0, 0x401f20, 0x7fc6d4567d10)        = 0x7fc6d4b00880
+++ exited (status 0) +++
```

`_Znwm` is an implementation of `operator new` (please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301899/llinking-znam-and-znwm)). 
Considering the [internal structure of `std::deque`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6292332/what-really-is-a-deque-in-stl/6292437#6292437) and the `#define _GLIBCXX_DEQUE_BUF_SIZE 512` line from STL implementation header `bits/stl_deque.h`, one may conclude that `_Znwm(64, 8, 0, 8)` allocates `std::deque`'s map for 8 pointers and `_Znwm(512, 128, 0, 128)` allocates one chunk of 512 bytes.

The question is: what is the reason not to postpone allocating these 512 bytes until the first element in `std::deque` is inserted?

Comment: Are you sure your leading statements are correct as per the C++ standard?

Comment: I described my implementation specifically.

Comment: Maybe you can add that information to your question.

Comment: Added requested information to the very beginning of the question.

Comment: added standard library as well

Comment: I think deferring the memory allocation also has its pros and cons.  If the memory allocation is deferred till first element is inserted, then it means if there is an insertion in the critical path, latency introduced in memory allocation can't be avoided as `deque::reserve()` doesn't exist (while `vector::reserve()` does).  But if the initial memory allocation is done when `deque` is constructed, the programmer can create the `deque` outside the critical path.

Comment: @HCSF, sorry for the late response, but I owe you a debt of gratitude for your comment. It sheds light on the rationale behind the design decisions made in `deque` implementation. It was exactly I wanted to know what I created the question almost three years ago.

Answer (score 2):

The most likely reason is that if the implementation did not do, every push_back(), push_front(), begin(), end(), insert() would have to check to see if the block of pointers to pages is allocated, and if not execute allocation of the block of pointers + the first page. That conditional checking slows these operations down, and the number of these operations is likely to dwarf the instances of a deque constructor executing.

The implementation has decided to stump up a minimum block of pointers + possibly an empty page. Effectively it is like a sentinel.

Would you really rather these common member functions be slower?

Comment: Anyway, `push_back()` and other member functions you mentioned have to check that the respective chunk (page in your terminology) has free space to place the element being added and allocate another chunk if necessary. From my point of view, the checking itself doesn't slow down the member functions significantly. It is memory allocated which does. Providing that we can't avoid memory allocation in the mentioned member functions, adding yet another one wouldn't change the situation considerably. Please correct me if I'm wrong.