# Are the functionality of _Znwm and _Znam the same in c++?

Tags: c++, llvm

I'm using llvm lately, and I found that new statements in cpp are translated to `_Znam` in llvm IR,  I know that 
`new` in cpp also call the function `_Znwm`, and `new []` call `_Znam`, so what's the difference between the functionality of these two functions?
What if I use `_Znwm` to allocate space for an array?

Example

```
a = new int*[10];
```

is compiled as

```
%2 = call i8* @_Znam(i64 80) #2
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [llinking @\_Znam and @\_Znwm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301899/llinking-znam-and-znwm)

Comment: Well, I checked that question before. But what I want to know is the difference between them. Specifically, what 's the difference between their behaviours when allocating space.

Comment: @yujie6 These functions are user-replaceable, but in the default library implementation, if not replaced by the user, they behave identically. Since C++11, the array version is supposed to just call the non-array version in the default implementation. Please edit your question to specify in detail what you want to know to avoid the close-as-duplicate votes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_Znwm` and `_Znam` are just mangled names for the functions

```
operator new(std::size_t)
```

and

```
operator new[](std::size_t)
```

respectively.

An (non-placement) array new expression calls the latter, while a (non-placement) non-array new expression calls the former to allocate memory.

These functions can be replaced by the user, but a default implementation is provided by the standard library. The default implementation of the array version simply calls the non-array version since C++11 and the non-array version allocates memory of the passed size, aligned suitably for all non-overaligned types, in some unspecified way, throwing the exception `std::bad_alloc` if allocation fails and otherwise returning a non-null pointer to the beginning of the allocated block.

So it behaves similar to `std::malloc`, except that the latter returns a null pointer if allocation fails, rather than throwing an exception. It is unspecified, but likely, that the default `operator new` implementation just uses `malloc` internally to do the allocation.

`malloc` should not call `operator new` or `operator new[]`, so I don't know why you think that it would translate to that in IR.

I don't think there is anything LLVM-specific here. Which allocation function is called is specified by the C++ standard. Only the names are mangled in an implementation-defined manner.

Also note that these calls are not *all* that the new expressions translate to. After calling `operator new`/`operator new[]` the new expression will also construct objects in the memory, which may require constructor calls to stores of values.